# can't perfrom apt update

Tags: package-management, updates, system

Hi I get this error when I run 'apt update'

```
- Err:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.90.159.172). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

I guess http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu is down. But how can I connect to a different server to update my system?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that server is down. To change servers, in the Dash type `software properties` and launch the app that shows up.

[image: the software properties app]

In the dropdown menu beside "Download from" you can pick another server.

Answer (score 1):

The list of Ubuntu mirrors can be found at

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

There are problems with

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.pregi.net-archive

If using Ubuntu Desktop, refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for details on changing the chosen server.

If you are using Ubuntu Server, refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine (or if you're like me and prefer command line anyway) to make changes to your sources.

In essence I'd recommend removing the "*ph.*" from in front of `archive.ubuntu.com`, so you use the main mirror instead of the currently down Philippines country mirror.

Comment: If using a desktop you can follow the other answer, I've answered this a number of times today, so I'm pasting my links here & will just push people here instead (I'm lazy)